# React + Bootstrap modal questions

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I am trying to put a modal dialog using react-bootstrap and having issues.

I have a "HintComponent" which consists of a bunch of buttons

```
  <div className="col-5 d-grid gap-2 borderGeneral">
    <button className="buttonGeneral" >Label here</button>
    <button className="buttonGeneral">SUMMARY</button>
  </div>
```

and I want to launch a Modal dialog on clicking a button.

Looking at the react-bootstrap site, I have the following (taken straight from the site)

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button';
import Modal from 'react-bootstrap/Modal';
import render from 'react-dom';

function Example() {
  const [show, setShow] = useState(false);

  const handleClose = () => setShow(false);
  const handleShow = () => setShow(true);

  return (
    <>
      <Button variant="primary" onClick={handleShow}>
        Launch demo modal
      </Button>

      <Modal show={show} onHide={handleClose}>
        <Modal.Header closeButton>
          <Modal.Title>Modal heading</Modal.Title>
        </Modal.Header>
        <Modal.Body>Woohoo, you're reading this text in a modal!</Modal.Body>
        <Modal.Footer>
          <Button variant="secondary" onClick={handleClose}>
            Close
          </Button>
          <Button variant="primary" onClick={handleClose}>
            Save Changes
          </Button>
        </Modal.Footer>
      </Modal>
    </>
  );
}

render(<Example />);
```

My issue is - how do I call the Modal from the HintComponent? If I try to import the Modal (in this case ) and call it as just  I get a warning about module having no exports.

Can anyone give me a hint?

Comment: Please see [ask], then revise your post title to ask a clear, _specific_ question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi very simple you need to use this component in your `HintComponent` and pass a prop `showModal={true}` but before this, you need to receive that prop in your modal component and set it in state using `React.useEffect`

So your final code will be like below:

## ModalComponent

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button';
import Modal from 'react-bootstrap/Modal';
import render from 'react-dom';

function Example(props) {
  const {showModal = false, onClose = ()=>{}} = props;
  const [show, setShow] = useState(showModal);

  React.useEffect(()=>{
    setShow(showModal);
  },[showModal]);

  const handleClose = () => {
   setShow(false);
   // just to have custom function for modal close which will be used can be used in HintComponent maybe you want to perform somehting else after modal close.
   typeof onClose === 'function' && onClose();
  };
  const handleShow = () => setShow(true);

  return (
    <>
      <Button variant="primary" onClick={handleShow}>
        Launch demo modal
      </Button>

      <Modal show={show} onHide={handleClose}>
        <Modal.Header closeButton>
          <Modal.Title>Modal heading</Modal.Title>
        </Modal.Header>
        <Modal.Body>Woohoo, you're reading this text in a modal!</Modal.Body>
        <Modal.Footer>
          <Button variant="secondary" onClick={handleClose}>
            Close
          </Button>
          <Button variant="primary" onClick={handleClose}>
            Save Changes
          </Button>
        </Modal.Footer>
      </Modal>
    </>
  );
}

render(<Example />);
```

I would recommend do not manage Modal visibility in its component but control it from the parent component in your case HintComponent.

Comment: Thanks Ali - I do get what you are saying about not controlling the visibility in the Modal, I was using the example code as a starting point.

However, how would I call the Modal? If I try to import the file, I get the error about no exports? I tried to import it and then used <Example showModal={true} /> but this was not correct

Comment: Create a separate file for the modal component and then import a component from that file but before this be sure that you have exported your component from that file for using `export ComponentName` or `export default Component` now the interesting part is to use the component in `HintComponent` If you are exporting component as default your import will look like `import ComponentName2 from "filepath"` and if you have exported component as `export ComponentName` your import will look like this `import {ComponentName} from "filepath"`

Comment: @Joseph checkout this sandbox you will understand better: https://codesandbox.io/s/elastic-dewdney-j1m865?file=/src/App.js